# Temporary concreate derived object passed where a reference to abstract base needed doesn't work?

Tags: c++, constructor, reference

I guess there is something about temporary objects that I don't understand.
Given the relationships:

```
class C {};

class F {
public:
    C getC() { return C(); };
};

class N {
public:
    N( C & base ){};
};
```

This works:

```
N n(C());
```

This doesn't work:

```
F f;
N n(f.getC()); //compile error
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-const reference (like `B& base`) can only bind to an lvalue.

`F::getC()` returns a `C` object by value, so the call expression `f.getC()` is an rvalue, not an lvalue.

---

The reason that `N n(C());` works, however, is due to an unrelated problem.

This does not declare an object.  It declares a function named `n` that returns `N` and takes a parameter of type "pointer to a function that has no parameters and returns `C`."

This is one manifestation of a language peculiarity known as the *most vexing parse*.  To change this to declare an object, you'd need one of the following:

```
N n = C();  // Use copy initialization
N n((C())); // Use more parentheses
```

Both of these would fail to compile, though, because both would attempt to bind the result of the rvalue expression `C()` to the non-const reference `B& base`.

---

A const reference (like `B const& base`) can bind to an rvalue, as can an rvalue reference (like `B&& base`) in C++11.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my code to reduce it to its minimum while you were commenting.  Now your comment doesn't reflect the names.  Although I understand it, other readers may not.  (should I revert it?)

Comment: if the ctor of `N` takes a `C&& base`, then everything works, doesn't it?

Comment: I'll re-post so the issue and resolution are clear to others.

Comment: Humm.. Stackoverflow won't let me re-post the issue code and resolution code because I'm too new.  Using const was the solution.

Comment: No worries.  I removed the last instance of `getConcrete()` from your question and updated the answer to match.